# Check blank value for response item using Serilizable annoation

Tags: android, serialization, android-mvvm

I am using `MVVVM` Pattern for API Call. Everything works good expect some blank values from server while serializing data using data class.

**I have server response**

```
"items": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "inspiration_id": "11",
    "name": "xxx",
    "categoryoptions": [
      "x",
      "y",
      "z"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "inspiration_id": "22",
    "name": "test",
    "categoryoptions": [

    ]
  },
```

For that i m using serialization using retrofit.

```
public class InspirationItemsData implements Serializable {

@Expose
@SerializedName("id")
private String id;
@Expose
@SerializedName("inspiration_id")
private String inspiration_id;
@Expose
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@Expose
@SerializedName("coordinates")
private String coordinates;
@Expose
@SerializedName("is_request")
private String is_request;

@Expose
@SerializedName("categoryoptions")
List<CategoryOptions> categoryOptionsList = new ArrayList<>();

public InspirationItemsData(String id, String inspiration_id, String name, String coordinates,String is_request) {
    this.id = id;
    this.inspiration_id = inspiration_id;
    this.name = name;
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
    this.is_request = is_request;
}

public List<CategoryOptions> getCategoryOptionsList() {
    return categoryOptionsList;
}

public void setCategoryOptionsList(List<CategoryOptions> categoryOptionsList) {
   this.categoryOptionsList = categoryOptionsList;
}

public String getIs_request() {
    return is_request;
}

public void setIs_request(String is_request) {
    this.is_request = is_request;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getInspiration_id() {
    return inspiration_id;
}

public void setInspiration_id(String inspiration_id) {
    this.inspiration_id = inspiration_id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCoordinates() {
    return coordinates;
}

public void setCoordinates(String coordinates) {
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
}
```

You can see in my data class that i have *categoryoptions* array which have alternate values. In some items it has values and some hasn't.

So while I am using this

> @Expose
>       @SerializedName("categoryoptions")
>       List categoryOptionsList = new ArrayList<>();

Then i am not able to get response. *onChanged()* method not called for observer nor getting response.

But if i comment above line that i am able to get response and able to display to UI. So for checking `null` and blank values i m using *@Expose* but it is not working.

**This is API Call**

```
 void getInspirationDetails() {
    inspirationDetailsModel.getInspirationDetails().observe(InspirationUploadDetailsActivity.this, new Observer<MainInspirationDetailsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(MainInspirationDetailsResponse mainInspirationDetailsResponse) {

            if (mainInspirationDetailsResponse != null) {
                if (mainInspirationDetailsResponse.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                    InspirationDetailData inspirationDetailData = mainInspirationDetailsResponse.getInspirationDetailData();
                    if (inspirationDetailData != null) {

                        Util.displayImage(InspirationUploadDetailsActivity.this, inspirationDetailData.getImage_file(), imgUploadedInsipration);

                        List<InspirationItemsData> inspirationItemsData = inspirationDetailData.getInspirationItemsData();
                        if (inspirationItemsData != null && inspirationItemsData.size() > 0) {

                            categoriesAdapter = new CategoriesAdapter(InspirationUploadDetailsActivity.this, inspirationItemsData);
                            rvCategories.setAdapter(categoriesAdapter);

                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Advanced help would be appreciated!

Comment: How does `CategoryOptions` class looks like ? I see that array of options as an `ArrayList` of `String` rather than your custom class.

Comment: Do you want to send values even if they are null ? . What library are you using gson or something else ?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I managed to use `List<String> categoryOptionsList = new ArrayList<>();` instead of `List<CategoryOptions> categoryOptionsList = new ArrayList<>();`